# Date formatting with XSLT / XPath

Tags: xslt, date, xpath, formatting

I have an XML document with the following node:

```
<date>09/01/2012</date>
```

How can i format the date with XSLT to retrieve another representation of the date?

Here ist the expected result:

```
<date>2012-01-09</date>
```

I tried the following rule, but it returns an empty string (i suppose because of the uncommon date input format):

```
<date><xsl:value-of select="format-date(date, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/></date>
```

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: XSL transformation is not very good at date formatting. I suggest using substring instead...

Comment: my header contains: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">` and i use the php xslt processor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Abdullah Battal, i came up with the following solution:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date, 7, 4), '-', substring(date, 4, 2), '-', substring(date, 1, 2))"/>
```